# jQuery animation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create something likes jQuery slider with a few points and with different distances between points

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="point point-1"></div>
  <div class="point point-2"></div>
  <div class="point point-3"></div>
  <div class="point point-4"></div>

  <div class="toddler"></div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
position: relative;
width: 500px;
height: 1px;
background: #000;
}
.point {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background: red;
}
.point-1 {
    left: 0;
}
.point-2 {
    left: 100px;
}
.point-3 {
    left: 250px;
}
.point-4 {
    right: 0px;
}

.toddler {
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 40px;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    background: blue;
    cursor:  pointer;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$.fn.slider = function () {
var startPoint = $(this).offset().left;
var endPoint = startPoint + $(this).width();

/*console.log(startPoint);
console.log(endPoint);*/

var points = $(this).find(".point");
var len = points.length;
/*console.log(len);*/

var pointsCoordsX = [];
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i != len; i++) {
    var coord = points.eq(i).offset().left;
    /*console.log(coord);*/
    pointsCoordsX.push(coord);
}

var toddler = $(this).find(".toddler");
toddler.bind('mousedown', function (e) {
    var toddlerW = toddler.width();
    var toddlerH = toddler.height();
    var toddlerX = toddler.offset().left;
    /*console.log(toddlerX);*/

    $(this).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
        var x = (e.pageX - toddlerX - (toddlerW / 2)) * (toddlerW > toddlerH ? (toddlerH / toddlerW) : 1);
        /*console.log(x);*/
        var PrevPointX;
        var NextPointX;
        for (i = 0; i != len - 1; i++) {
            if (toddlerX >= pointsCoordsX[i] && toddlerX <= pointsCoordsX[i + 1]) {
                PrevPointX = pointsCoordsX[i];
                NextPointX = pointsCoordsX[i + 1];
            }
        }
        /*console.log(PrevPointX);
        console.log(NextPointX);*/
        if (x > 0) {
            var diffX1 = NextPointX - toddlerX;
            /*console.log(diffX);*/
            $(this).animate({'right': + '+=' + diffX1});
        }
        else {
            var diffX2 = toddlerX - PrevPointX;
            /*console.log(diffX);*/
            $(this).animate({'left': + '+=' + diffX2});
        }
    });
});
};


$(".wrapper").slider();
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/vvxnb0u9/60/

I don't understand why my animation doesn't work here ?

Comment: I got it working in a weird way, but first observation: `$(this).animate({'right': + '+=' + diffX1});` should be `$(this).animate({'right': '+=' + diffX1});` on both lines.

Comment: And I would advise `for (i = 0; i < len; i++)` more than `for (i = 0; i != len - 1; i++)`

Comment: Well, I tried to use `$(this).animate({'right': '+=' + diffX1});` but it doesnt help http://jsfiddle.net/vvxnb0u9/70/

Comment: Rems solution works and as he said it looks really weird.

Comment: You can check code http://jsfiddle.net/vvxnb0u9/70/ and you will see it doesn't work as I said.

Comment: With [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vvxnb0u9/60/) I got something working weirdly. When you click on the toddler, if you go to its left right after, the toddler gets shifted to the right, from a distance equal to the one between the toddler and the previous point.

Comment: If you are trying to build a slider with no particular behaviour except the points in between, maybe you could try [this thing](https://code.google.com/p/threedubmedia/downloads/detail?name=jquery.event.drag-1.2.min.js&can=4&q=)?  [DEMO](http://threedubmedia.com/demo/drag/)

Comment: I would rather use that as it looks pretty much customizable and flexible. It will spare you the pain of managing mousemove events and dragging behaviour in general.

Comment: Keep me aware of how it goes! It might this plugin for my own needs someday, if you give me a good feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Well I thought this was a fun problem, so I gave it a try. I was not sure about what you wanted to achieve, so I took some liberties (a lot, actually). But, if you understand what I did, you'll probably be able to rearrange it so it can do what you have in mind.

The main liberty I took was to allow the user to click anywhere near the bar without being forced to drag the slider (which is still allowed). Looking at your original fiddle, I'm sure you can undo that easily.

Then I deleted some code which was processing the next / previous point to reach. This part is pure algorithmic so you also can undo that with your own code.

I replaced your code with:

```
// the "clickable" area surronds the bar
$(".clickable").bind('mousedown', function (e) {
    toddlerW = toddler.width();
    toddlerH = toddler.height();
    toddlerX = toddler.offset().left;
});

$(".clickable").bind('mouseup', function (e) {

    // the distance to add / remove is the distance between
    // the current mouse position and the old toddler position
    // (draw it on paper if needed)
    var x = e.pageX - toddlerX - toddlerW / 2;

    // save the new toddler position
    toddlerX = e.pageX;

    // let's ride !
    toddler.animate({'left': '+=' + x}, "slow");

});
```

Tell me if that's too much away from what you need.

If you want the toddler to be anywhere on the bar: http://jsfiddle.net/9r8qh4cu/

If you want the toddler to be on the exact points: http://jsfiddle.net/aogohya8/

A more general example (enhanced the slider capabilities): http://jsfiddle.net/df2gjvh9/